# Node js if/else not functioning properly using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

```
var available = await page.waitForSelector('[name="commit"]')
if (available) {
    await page.click('[name="commit"]')
    console.log('success');
} else {
    await browser.close();
    console.log('unavailble');
}
```

'''

I would like the code to look for a selector, if it has it then continue, but if not, i want it to retry again. What can be changed to make this function properly? thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say "not functioning properly" - what do you mean? do either of the console.log's occur? Also, what is the value of `available`? a `console.log(available)` will show you this for debugging

Answer (score 0):

**Await** works only with **Async** function.
Move your code inside **async** function.

```
async function function_name() {
  //your code come here
  var available = await page.waitForSelector('[name="commit"]')
  if (available) {
    await page.click('[name="commit"]')
    console.log('woohoooo');
 } else {
    await browser.close();
    console.log('item unavailble');
 }
}
```

Comment: I would assume if the code were not inside an async function, the error produced would be obvious to the OP